# Rails nested association is not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m trying to save a nested association, but for some reason it’s not working.  Does anyone see anything wrong with this?

````
Order:
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :replenishable_products, through: :order_items
  has_many :order_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end


OrderItem
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :replenishable_product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replenishable_product
end

ReplenishableProduct
class ReplenishableProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_item
end

Order Controller
def create
  @order = @customer.orders.new(order_params)
  authorize @order

  if @order.save
    render json: @order, serializer: ::V1::OrderSerializer, status: :created
  else
    render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(order_items_attributes: [:quantity, :product_id, :selling_unit_of_measure_id,
                                replenishable_product_attributes: [:product_id, :salesperson_id,
                                :customer_id, :replenishable_date]])
end


Example request data:
```
{"order"=><ActionController::Parameters {"additional_tax_total"=>"8.27", "basket_id"=>"1", "custom_order_number"=>"pf000", "customer_attributes"=>{"contact_name"=>"Jason Test", "email"=>"new@test.com", "phone"=>"6095453234"}, "order_items_attributes"=>[{"product_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"5", "replenishable_product_attributes"=>{"customer_id"=>"1", "product_id"=>"1", "replenishable_date"=>"2017-06-09T13:00:39-04:00", "salesperson_id"=>"1"}, "selling_unit_of_measure_id"=>"1"}, {"product_id"=>"2", "quantity"=>"5", "selling_unit_of_measure_id"=>"2"}], "payment_total"=>"103.31", "salesperson_id"=>"1", "shipping_address"=>"Test", "special_instructions"=>"test"} permitted: false>, "customer_id"=>"1", "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/orders", "action"=>"create"}
```
````

So every other association is saving fine, but the `replenishable_product` is not being saved.  I looked over it a few times and I don't see why it wouldn't be saving.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Update the question with new method of orders controller.

Comment: @Pavan There is no new method, it's posted from client side app.

Comment: Do you get any error in the server log? If so, please update the question with it.

Comment: What is order_params if you log it out?  What happens if you put a ! on the end of save so it is `save!`?